# Upload Image To Collection Using InstaSharp or InstagramApiSharp?

Tags: c#, instasharp

I want to upload images to my Instagram account using an Api like InstaSharp or InstagramApiSharp on Github and C#. But have no idea how to do it.

There is **UploadPhotoAsync()** but can't specify what collection it should be uploaded to.

Anyone have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You just pass InstaImage and String for caption.

```
InstaImage iamge = new InstaImage
            {
                URI = new Uri(Path.GetFullPath("image.jpg"), UriKind.Absolute).LocalPath,
                Width = 720,
                Height = 889,
            };


        IResult<InstaMedia> postResult = await _instaApi.UploadPhotoAsync(iamge,"caption");
```